# How to disable a pc to connect to internet with usb modem

Tags: laptop, connection, usb-modem

I want to make a configuration in a computer in order to make it unable to connect to internet with modem. I've tried to give it a static ip adress but it works only with WIFI connections. Have you some idea how could i proceed ?

Comment: What OS do you use? By modem you mean *ethernet*? what is the adapter you want to disable? what have you tried so far and why did it failed? please elaborate more.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 , and I'm talking about 3G modem

Comment: You're still missing the "_what have you tried so far and why did it failed? please elaborate more_" part. Have you tried disabling it from the adapter settings' control panel page?

Comment: As I said in my question I've only tried to go to "Wireless Network connection status -> properties -> IP v4 and change the setting for "use the following Ip adress" but its works only for unable computer to connect with WIFI